# Add a where clause while using firstOrNew()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I make a call to an API which returns a list of clients.  I then convert this to XML:

```php
$clientListXML = new \SimpleXMLElement($clients);
```

What I then need to do is create this client within my system. This is normally straight forward, but I wanted to add a clause onto it.
At the moment I am trying something like this:

```php
foreach ($clientListXML->Clients->Client as $client) {
    $client = Client::firstOrNew(['clientName' => $client->Name])
        ->where($client->Name, 'like', '%' . 'ABC');
    //other parameters
    $client->save();
}
```

So when it loops the XML, I only want it to save the clients that have a name like ABC.
In other words I do not want all of the clients within the XML saved, only a select few.

Is it possible to add a where like clause in this type of scenario?

Thanks

Comment: Notice that `%ABC` = Starting with ABC. `%ABC%` = contain ABC. `ABC%` = ends with ABC.

Comment: Doing this on a first and new however returns Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()

Comment: It makes no sense to filter if you're creating. I'd check the name before or after.

NB: `firstOrNew()` and `firstOrCreate()` return a model element that has the same attributes you pass in the array.

Comment: Thanks, thought so.  I ended up using strpos before I created the model.  Thanks